# Screenshot on my mac without permission?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, mac-pro

Sometimes I hear sound of making screenshot on my mac - what can it be? How can I check if there is any spyware which takes screenshots?

Comment: I'd really think some kind of 'spyware' would try its best to not alert you to the fact by triggering the associated sound.

Comment: Take a look [at these answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27245/88313) and see if they help.  It's not a duplicate of your question but it's similar.

Answer (score 1):

Type ps -ax in the Mac terminal to view all running processes. Find suspicious ones and abort them. You can abort the process by using the **kill** command followed by the process ID (PID).