# Is MacBook able to turn on the isight camera even the green light indicator is burned or damaged?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, camera

I am referring to the URL below stated that no software able to bypass or turn off the light not even the macos firmwares.

[Does a modern MacBook's green "camera light" always turn on when the camera is activated?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313504/does-a-modern-macbooks-green-camera-light-always-turn-on-when-the-camera-is-a)

I wonder what if my Mac book Pro green light indicator is damaged or burned, will the iSight camera still able to be activated?

Answer (score 1):

The light is in series with the camera, so the camera will only turn on if the circuit is unbroken.

It may be possible for the light to be broken but still pass electrical current through it.

The only real way to know is to test it. I wouldn't advise deliberately trying to damage the light in order to turn it off.